# Why is an Imported Function Slower in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import

I tried restructuring my code to have a function defined in another file and noticed it seems to be running a bit slower. I'm wondering if anyone knows how to prevent this slowdown or if there is a known reason for this. I had understood imports in python to be the same as copy-pasting your code so this slow down is strange to me.

An example:

```
from datetime import datetime
from import_test import small_test_import

def small_test(x):
    return x+1

start1 = datetime.now()
for i in range(x):
    Z=small_test(1)
end1 = datetime.now()
print(end1-start1) #1.355964

start2 = datetime.now()
for i in range(x):
    Z=small_test_import(1)
end2 = datetime.now()
print(end2-start2) #1.433045
```

or to use timeit:

```
def wrapper(func, *args, **kwargs):
    def wrapped():
         return func(*args, **kwargs)
    return wrapped

wrapped = wrapper(small_test, 1)
print(timeit.timeit(wrapped,number=x)) #1.8407
wrapped = wrapper(small_test_imported, 1)
print(timeit.timeit(wrapped, number=x)) #2.1006
```

I realize this isn't a huge time difference but it is consistent.

Comment: I can not repreduce this with `timeit`.

Comment: For 100M runs, I get `5.633208999999624` for the imported, and `6.241973999996844` for the non-imported. But it is possible that due to "pagination" some function is faster than the other, but this is more "ad random" (sometimes the first function can be split over two pages, sometimes the other).

Comment: Results vary on my machine depending on whether I use python, python3, or pypy, and are not consistent either.

Comment: An import is NOT the same as copy and pasting your code - in languages like C++ it is, but Python is a little more complicated. Still, if you're doing the "from ... import ..." form, looking up the name in the namespace shouldn't be slowing you down... I suspect it has something to do with Python having to get context info from the other module, which it already has for in-module calls. My advice is to make sure you know about this, but not worry about it much. :P

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. As it seems to be an issue with my set up, not python, should I close the question?

Comment: 102 ns ± 9.47 ns per loop vs 107 ns ± 4.25 ns per loop for the imported one with `timeit` for me in python3, so no significant difference.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I added code for how I'm performing the test using timeit, although I have little experience with that so please excuse me if it's less then ideal

Comment: I definitely agree with the advice to "not worry about it much" but I am less convinced that this is somehow due to your setup. (I see it on my machine too.) I'm pretty sure it has to have *something* to do with Python, even if that something happens to be extremely esoteric. If it's esoteric enough that Python 2 behaves differently than Python 3 (in a reliable fashion), then that is a clue right there.

Answer (score 1):

The time diffs you are printing in your script show a difference of around 0.8 seconds, if I'm not mistaken? The imported function is most probably not slower, but your test setup gives it a disadvantage: it has to clean up the existing `Z` object. Your script re-uses the variable `Z` and therefore, the second for-loop has to clean up the object (the returned value) you bound to `Z` in the first test.

Try the measurement again with this code:

```
start1 = datetime.now()
for i in range(x):
    X = small_test(1)
end1 = datetime.now()
print(end1-start1)

start2 = datetime.now()
for i in range(x):
    Y = small_test_import(1)
end2 = datetime.now()
print(end2-start2)
```

It should not produce a notable difference.

Comment: I tried removing the assignment so it just calls the function and both became faster but the imported one is still slower. (1.157822s vs 1.266880s). This seems to be an issue with my set up though based on the comments to the question

Comment: I'm pretty sure this isn't it. The "cleanup" you're talking about is garbage-collecting the previous result, but this would have to happen to every previous result on every iteration. In other words, if you do `X = small_test(1)` in a loop with one million iterations, then you have to clean up 999999 results within that loop. If you use the same variable name for the imported test, and run it a million times, then the imported version has 1000000 previous results to clean up instead of 999999. Not a big enough disadvantage to account for the difference.

Comment: Anyway, the "standard" way to correct for any kind of miscellaneous advantage of "going first" is to simply try the entire test again, but reverse who goes first.

Comment: @JohnY I have tried reversing the order in which I test and that no effect.

Comment: @Supamee - I know. That is one reason why this answer doesn't seem right to me. It's also one reason why I don't think you should be so dismissive of your question.